# explicit recurrence formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I need to verify the procedure for solving the recurrent equation. I solved it this way, but I don't have much experience with it, so I don't know if it's right.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't use pictures. Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: My skills at reading cursive Czech (or is it Slovak?) are a bit limited, but from what I can read it seems reasonable.

Comment: yes its Czech :). I let it be, probably everyone understands what I meant

Comment: No, your computation isn't good. You cannot apply the characteristic polynomial technique when variable terms like $2^n-3$ occur. This technique works only with constant coefficients.

Comment: In the textbook we have similar examples calculated in this way

Comment: One thing is sure: if you have a solution $a_n$, $a'_n:=ka_n+2^n$ is also a solution for any constant $k$.

Answer (score 1):

I can advise you two methods:

(Edit) **Method of generating functions**:

We are going to obtain a particular solution, which is often the most difficult part.

Let us consider the case where:

$$a_0=1, a_1=2, a_2=3$$

with the following terms :

$$a_3=11, \
a_4=36, \ a_5=96, \ a_6=239, \ a_7=579, \ 
a_8=1364, \ \text{etc.}$$

In this case, one gets the following formula, very coherent to yours (it suffices to add the general solution of the associated homogeneous recurrence):

$$a_n=(29/50) \cos(\pi n/2)+(53/50) \sin(\pi n/2)-(27/25) \times 2^n+(3/2)+(4/5) \times n 2^n\tag{0'}$$

Let us establish it using the technique of generating functions.

Let the formal series $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ be the generating function of the sequence $a_n$.

It is not difficult to verify that, when multiplying initial relationship:

$$a_{n}-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-2a_{n-3}=2^n-3\tag{1'}$$

by $x^n$ and then suming for all $x^n$, we get:

$$g(x)(1-2x+x^2-2x^3)-\underbrace{(3+x-x^2)}_{p(x)}=\frac{1}{1-2x}-\frac{3}{1-x}\tag{2'}$$

where the fractions on the RHS are the generating functions of sequence $2^n$ and constant sequence $3$ resp. The presence of polynomial $p(x)$ is justified by the fact that the recurrence between the $a_n$ uses four terms, therefore cannot take place before degree $3$.

From (2'), one can deduce the partial fraction decomposition:

$$g(x)=\dfrac{53x+29}{50(x^2+1)}-\dfrac{3}{2(x-1)}+\dfrac{47}{25(2x-1)}+\dfrac{4}{5(2x-1)^2}\tag{3'}$$

(3') gives (0').

---

**Second method**  using "auxiliary sequences" (in the initial version of this answer, it was placed in front) with the objective to get rid progressively from the "spurious" terms using :

Let us write the initial relationship

$$a_{n}-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-2a_{n-3}=2^n-3\tag{1}$$

and its equivalent "shifted version":

$$a_{n+3}-2a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}-2a_{n}=2^{n+3}-3\tag{2}$$

Take the combination $(3) = 1 \times (2) - 8 \times (1)$ giving

$$(a_{n+3}-8a_n)-2(a_{n+2}-8a_{n-1})+(a_{n+1}-8a_{n-2})-2(a_{n}-8a_{n-3})=21\tag{3}$$

Otherwise said, by defining

$$b_{n}:=a_{n+3}-8a_n \tag{4}$$

$$b_n-2b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}-2b_{n-3}=21\tag{3'}$$

Now, we must get rid of constant $21$. This is done by writing (3') under the form:

$$(b_n+k)-2(b_{n-1}+k)+(b_{n-2}+k)-2(b_{n-3}+k)=21\tag{5}$$

for a certain unknown $k$ that must be such that $-2k=21 \iff k=-\dfrac{21}{2}$

Setting

$$c_n:=b_n-\dfrac{21}{2}\tag{6}$$

relationship (5) has become:

$$c_n-2c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}-2c_{n-3}=0\tag{7}$$

Now, and only now, you are "authorized" to use the characteristic polynomial technique giving you the general expression of the $c_n$, from which you will get, using (6) under the form $b_n=c_n+\dfrac{21}{2}$ the general expression of $b_n$, then, using (4), you will get a relationship that you will write 3 times:

$$a_{n+3}-8a_n=b_n, \ a_{n+2}-8a_{n-1}=b_{n-1}, \ a_{n+1}-8a_{n-2}=b_{n-2}$$

and by combinations of these equations, get rid, once more, of the "spurious" RHS.

Comment: See the important changes made.